# Inspect Response Header if Open Chrome DevTools AFTER a Page Issue?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know how to inspect a response header via DevTools. However, always keep DevTools open when browse websites will make the space smaller for the pages. So normally I close it.

However, from time to time, when I visit a webpage, I may encounter issues. This time when I open the DevTools, I cannot see the response header for the issue. If I try to visit the same webpage again, then the issue will disappear.

So, how to inpsect a response header if I open the DevTools after the issue occurs?